# Only index URL is working after hosting laravel project to a live server

Tags: laravel

I uploaded my laravel project today for the first time but only the index route is found.On the other route's i'm getting a "404 Not Found".What could be the issue?

Comment: Enable mod_rewrite

Comment: did you change index.php -> autoload path?? After hosting?

Comment: I'll enable the mod_rewrite and let you know how it goes.The change's I made in my index.php file is in the "require __DIR__." and "$app = require_once __DIR__." to point to my project folder because I saved all the file in a new folder at the root level.

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable mod_rewrite in your web server so that laravel can process your routes correctly, if your using Apache, do this in your terminal

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

then you need to edit your vhost file and add this

```
<Directory /var/www/neonwriter/public>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Restart apache2 after

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

or

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to run:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

Read also carefully about deployment project on serwer, here you find all the most important infromations from official documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/deployment

Good luck!

Comment: Hey buddy when I run php artisan route:cache im getting this error

Comment: In Route.php line 817:

  Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

Comment: If you have closure in routes you can not make php artisan route

Comment: I cleared every instance of a closure from my routes file but i'm still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I was able to solve this problem.I realized that my .htaccess file wasn't at the root level which was causing the problem.I solved my problem with this and hope that if your having the same problem,this will be helpful.Cheers :)